# Setting activeTintColor on a custom drawer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am creating a drawer using DrawerNavigator. I was highlighting the current selected screen on the drawer by setting a activeTintColor value

```
contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#65433d',
    }
```

Now I decided to customize my drawer by setting a contentComponent. So looks my code like

```
export default DrawerNavigator({
  Page1: {
    screen: Page1
  },
  Page2: {
    screen: Page2
  },
  Page3: {
    screen: Page3
  }
}, {
  contentComponent: SideMenu,
  drawerWidth: 300
});
```

In SlideMenu.js

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import styles from './SideMenu.style';
import {NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation';
import {ScrollView, Text, View} from 'react-native';

class SideMenu extends Component {
  navigateToScreen = (route) => () => {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: route
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.sectionHeadingStyle}>
              Section 1
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.navSectionStyle}>
              <Text style={styles.navItemStyle} onPress={this.navigateToScreen('Page1')}>
              Page1
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.sectionHeadingStyle}>
              Section 2
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.navSectionStyle}>
              <Text style={styles.navItemStyle} onPress={this.navigateToScreen('Page2')}>
                Page2
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.navItemStyle} onPress={this.navigateToScreen('Page3')}>
                Page3
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
          <Text>This is my fixed footer</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

SideMenu.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.object
};

export default SideMenu;
```

How can I set a different color for the selected menu item?

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 way to identify current screen. `navigation` prop has sub prop containing `routeName`. You can check and render `SideMenu` component accordingly.

Firs option is to send it through `DrawerNavigator`

**Example**

```
export default DrawerNavigator({
  Page1: { screen: Page1 },
  Page2: { screen: Page2 },
  Page3: { screen: Page3 }
}, {
  contentComponent: (props) => (
       <SideMenu currentScreen={props.navigation.state.routeName} {...props} />
  ),
  drawerWidth: 300
});
```

Second way is to directly read it inside the component.

**Example**

```
class SideMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { currentScreen: props.navigation.state.routeName };
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <SomeView
        style={[styles.view, (this.state.currentScreen === 'Page1' ? styles.active : {} )]}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello 
Can you help me..
I am getting ''currentScreen: undefined" evry time if i have follow all your code..